# Cannot POST / using express and body-parser

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

This question has already been asked but the other answers did not help me. I have a login form parsing username and password and authenticate it from database and I keep getting `Cannot POST /` error.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/login');
});
// route for user Login
app.route('/login')
    .get(sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
        res.render('login.pug');
    })
    .post((req, res) => {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({ where: { username: username } }).then(function (user) {
        if (!user) {
            res.redirect('/login');
        } else if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
            res.redirect('/login');
        } else {
            req.session.user = user.dataValues;
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('express is running on port 3000');
});
```

pug file for login:

```
form(action='/', method='POST')        
     input(type='text',name='username',placeholder= 'Username', required='')
     input(type='password', name='password', placeholder='Password', required='')
     input(type='submit', value='Login')
```

Where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try login on `/login` route, but send post to `/`. Change your pug to

```
form(action='/login', method='POST')
```

BTW: If you use [Passport](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/) you can easily add other login method: Google, FB, twitter, ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the express app handles the post

Do this:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})
```

Comment: It's not a solution, but your answer has led me to solve the problem. :)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to use JWT token authentication, so you don't have to worry about first calling './get' on /login and then './post' to check session.

With JWT you can token you can simply provide a token validation, which will automatically redirect to the login page in case of token expiration or validation when redirecting to a new page.

Also, if you explore more about JWT then you will find, you can pass data also in a token, it could be Permissions as per the user login.

Comment: JWT for logging in on the site? It's a big exaggeration. JWT is great when communicating with the API. Passort and Local strateggy are better.

Comment: @bato3 I answered more in terms of API and I realize Hossein needed more help in Authentication and for that Passport and Local strategy are better. For the future JWT is good to have with passport.

Comment: I do not think that JWT is bad, only that it is not suitable everywhere. Besides, you need `.post / .get` to generate the token, and that was the problem with this moment.